# How to create a Python generator in lua?

Tags: python, lua, generator, coroutine

I'm trying to convert this Python code into lua, but I really can't get my head around it. The problem is that in python, the for loop automatically resumes the function after it has yielded, but I'm not sure of how to do this in lua. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code where the function is defined:

```py
def _good_paths(self, x, y, dx, dy, budget, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    if budget >= 0:
        yield (), (x, y, dx, dy)
    if budget <= 0:
        return
    seen.add((x, y))  # Remember cleaning this up (A)
    x1, y1 = x + dx, y + dy
    if (x1, y1) not in seen:
        for path, end in self._good_paths(
                x1, y1, -dy, dx, budget - self.lr_price, seen):
            yield (L,) + path, end
        for path, end in self._good_paths(
                x1, y1, dy, -dx, budget - self.lr_price, seen):
            yield (R,) + path, end
        seen.add((x1, y1))  # Remember cleaning this up (B)
        x2, y2 = x1 + dx, y1 + dy
        if (x2, y2) not in seen:
            for path, end in self._good_paths(
                    x2, y2, dx, dy, budget - self.t_price, seen):
                yield (T,) + path, end
        seen.remove((x1, y1))  # Clean up (B)
    seen.remove((x, y))  # Clean up (A)
```

Here is where the function is used:

```py
def prepare(self, budget):
    dx0, dy0 = 0, 1
    for path, (x, y, dx, dy) in self._good_paths(0, 0, dx0, dy0, budget):
        self.list.append((path, x, y, dx, dy))
        self.inv[x, y, dx, dy].append(path)
```

Here is my attempt at converting to lua (in same order):

```
function mitm:good_paths(x, y, dx, dy, budget, seen)
    local co
    co = coroutine.create(function(x, y, dx, dy, budget, seen)
        if seen == nil then
            seen = {}
        end

        if budget >= 0 then
            coroutine.yield({}, x, y, dx, dy)
        end
        if budget <= 0 then
            return
        end

        if not Misc.checkInList(seen, x .. ", " .. y) then
            table.insert(seen, x .. ", " .. y)
        end

        local x1, y1 = x + dx, y + dy
        if not Misc.checkInList(seen, x1 .. ", " .. y1) then
            for path, thisEnd in self:good_paths(x1, y1, -dy, dx, budget - self.lr_price, seen) do
                coroutine.yield(table.insert(path, L, 1), thisEnd)
            end

            for path, thisEnd in self:good_paths(x1, y1, dy, -dx, budget - self.lr_price, seen) do
                coroutine.yield(table.insert(path, R, 1), thisEnd)
            end

            table.insert(seen, x1 .. ", " .. y1)

            local x2, y2 = x1 + dx, y1 + dy

            if not Misc.checkInList(seen, x2 .. ", " .. y2) then
                for path, thisEnd in self:good_paths(x2, y2, dx, dy, budget - self.t_price, seen) do
                    coroutine.yield(table.insert(path, T, 1), thisEnd)
                end
            end

            local removeIndex
            for index, val in pairs(seen) do
                if val == x1 .. ", " .. y1 then
                    removeIndex = index

                    break
                end
            end

            table.remove(seen, removeIndex)
        end

        local removeIndex
        for index, val in pairs(seen) do
            if val == x .. ", " .. y then
                removeIndex = index

                break
            end
        end

        table.remove(seen, removeIndex)
    end)

    local iterator = function ()
        local code, path1, x1, y1, dx1, dy1 = coroutine.resume(co, x, y, dx, dy, budget, seen)
        return path1, x1, y1, dx1, dy1
    end

    return iterator
end



function mitm:prepare(budget)
    local dx0, dy0 = 0, 1

    for path, x, y, dx, dy in self:good_paths(0, 0, dx0, dy0, budget) do
        print(path, x, y, dx, dy)

        table.insert(self.list, {path, x, y, dx, dy})
        if not self.inv[x .. ", " .. y .. ", " .. dx .. ", " .. dy] then
            self.inv[x .. ", " .. y .. ", " .. dx .. ", " .. dy] = {}
        end
        table.insert(self.inv[x .. ", " .. y .. ", " .. dx .. ", " .. dy], path)
    end
end
```

So I guess my question is: how would I make this function run repeatedly until it doesn't yield anymore like it would in python (create a generator-like system in lua)

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: I've edited the post, hope it is okay now.

Comment: Better, yes.  You'll have a better chance to get a good response if you provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I won't be that person, as I haven't touched Lua for five years.

Comment: I don't know if `lua` can create generator but in many situations you can create convert code to normal function which create empty list at start and it append result to this list instead of yielding - and finnaly it returns this full list.

Comment: You should use 4 variables instead of `thisEnd`.  The rest of your code looks ok.  What problem do you have now?

Answer (score 0):

When a coroutine can no longer be called, `coroutine.status` will return `"dead"`. In addition, we can define an iterator function `range_co` to make it look more like a Python generator.

```lua
function range_co(co)
  return function()
    local err, v = coroutine.resume(co)
    if coroutine.status(co) ~= "dead" then
      return v
    end
  end
end

square10 = coroutine.create(function ()
  for i=0,10 do
    coroutine.yield(i*i)
  end
end)

for v in range_co(square10) do
  print(v)
end
```